# Right Click context - Search folder .txt & .log files

Tags: powershell, search

Still new to PowerShell and have been creating automation scripts, checks and balances and anything I can think of to make our jobs easier day to day. The contract we are working on are extremely tight when it comes to applications and forbids opensource\freeware applications. So I have been working on using powershell to do the job.

Here is what I have so far:
1. Created HKCR\Directory\Shell\powershell (default) Reg_sz Search Folder Text & Log files
2. Created HKCR\Directory\Shell\powershell\command (default) Reg_sz

```
C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -file c:\temp\RightClickSearch.ps1 -NoExit -Command Set-Location -LiteralPath '%L'
```

I was able to get the right click to launch and the script opens up and prompts me for my keyword to search. Problem is, I can't seem to figure out how to pass the location to the script properly.

RightClickSearch.ps1 
*(I know the $path isn't set, before it was hardcoded and I know I have to pass a variable to it from the menu)*

```
$promt = (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Search Keyword")
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include *.txt, *.log -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $promt | Format-table -AutoSize -Property LineNumber,Filename,Path
Pause
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your call to `powershell.exe`:

- You can't specify both the `-File` and `-Command` parameters.  You can only specify one of them.
- Whichever one you *do* specify, it has to be the last parameter in the command.  In your example, the `-NoExit` and `-Command` parameters would be ignored.  (Type `powershell.exe -?` for an explanation.)

The good news is that PowerShell scripts themselves can accept arguments by using the `param` keyword.  Simply declare the parameter at the top of your script:

```
param ($Path)
$promt = (Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Search Keyword")
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Include *.txt, *.log -Recurse | Select-String -Pattern $promt | Format-table -AutoSize -Property LineNumber,Filename,Path
Pause
```

You call it from the command line like this:

```
C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -File c:\temp\RightClickSearch.ps1 -Path '%L'
```

Since `$Path` is the one and only parameter, you don't even have to specify its name:

```
C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -File c:\temp\RightClickSearch.ps1 '%L'
```

Ironically, you could use the `-Command` parameter in exactly the same way.  The only difference is that your script file will not be dot-sourced, but that won't matter in the example you gave.